# extraer valor de consulta desde una variable en mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

tengo una consulta en un trigger de mysql con una consulta similar a

```
BEGIN
    set @correos=(select correo from tabla_correos group by correo)
END
```

la tabla tiene la siguiente estructura e informacion

```
|     tabla_correos      |
-------------------------
|correo1@mio.com         |
|correo2@mio2.com        |
```

al final quiero como resultado los correos de la siguiente manera

```
"correo1@mio.com,correo2@mio2.com"
```

pero no se como concatenar los correos como string en una nueva variable, no se como extraer cada valor, llevo dias revisando la documentacion pero ando perdido, me podrian ayudar?

Comment: ¿Puedes expandir tu ejemplo un poco más? En particular, ¿cómo pensabas concatenar los correos? ¿Cual es el resultado final que deseas?

Comment: Y si puedes, muestra un ejemplo mas completo de tu trigger. Obviamente, el ejemplo que pusistes no puede funcionar. Pero quisiera entender por qué usas un *user-defined variable*, porque el valor de esta es visible fuera del trigger. Eso no parece correcto.

Comment: Hola @sstan le agregue el principio y fin del trigger, espero se entienda. solo conozco este tipo de variable, hay otros?, no puse como pensaba concatenarlos porque eso es lo que aun no se como podria hacerlo. espero me puedan ayudar, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es concatenar los correos directamente en la consulta usando la función [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select group_concat(distinct correo)
  from tabla_correos
```

Esto de una vez te devuelve todos los correos separados por comas.

La función [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) acepta otras opciones en caso necesites separar los valores diferentemente o en un orden específico.

Comment: es exacto lo que necesitaba, gracias